# How can I make an Ext JS 4 model association use an existing store rather than creating its own?

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, extjs4

I have the following models set up (simplified):

```js
Ext.define('UserGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['GroupID', 'UserID'],
    idProperty: '',
    associations: [{
        type: 'belongsTo',
        model: 'User',
        primaryKey: 'UserID',
        foreignKey: 'UserID',
        name: 'users'
    }]
)};

Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'UserID',
    associations: [{
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'UserGroup',
        primaryKey: 'UserID',
        foreignKey: 'UserID',
        name: 'userGroups'
    }]
});
```

I already have existing stores loaded for each of these models, with plenty of associated data.
When I try to access the `UserGroup` association from `User`, I get no data back.

```js
Ext.getStore('User').getAt(12).userGroups().count(); // returns 0
```

I know this is because assocation is creating its own store.  So far, I can only get the appropriately associated data by

```js
Ext.getStore('User').getAt(12).userGroups().load();
```

which makes a call to the server to get that information, but then I have to use a callback and wait for a response.

So, how can I specify a store for the `userGroups` assocation to use so it doesn't request data from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, there are two possible solutions:

1. Override `Ext.data.HasManyAssociation.createStore`.
2. Pass the data from original store to [`Ext.data.HasManyAssociation.storeConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.HasManyAssociation-cfg-storeConfig):

   ```
   Ext.define('User', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       idProperty: 'UserID',
       associations: [{
           type: 'hasMany',
           storeConfig: {
             data: originalStore.getRange()
           },
           // ...
       }]
   });
   ```

Comment: Awesome, that looks fantastic. I hope to give it a try this week. Thanks!